# replace all substring matching numbers in square brackets -php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

it might be very easy but i could not do it..

given a string:

```
$str="i have an apple[1], and another one [2], and another[3]";
```

i want to replace `[1]`, `[2]` .. with `<tag id=1> <tag id=2>`

i tried `$str2 = preg_replace('/[([1-9][0-9]*)]/', '<tag id=1>', $str);`

but can not insert a variable to do

`$str2 = preg_replace('/[([1-9][0-9]*)]/', '<tag id=$var>', $str);`

the regex i am using is also a problem, it works for some cases but does not for some :(

any help is deeply appreciated..

EDIT:
as @m42 and @scibuff pointed out, valid regex would be: `/\[([1-9][0-9]*)\]/`

but how to increment for each replacement?

EDIT 2:
i misunderstood M42's answer, thanks.

But what if i have another string;

```
str2="i have an egg [4], and another egg [5]";
```

how can i continue the increment started by first `preg_replace`?

i mean, desired result is:

```
i have an apple <tag id=1>,... i have an egg [4]..
```

EDIT 3: SOLVED by M42
-in fact second part of the question is meaningless, `preg_replace` will increment continously.. thanks all!!

Comment: you need to escape the `[` and `]`, e.g. `/\[([1-9][0-9]*)\]/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$str2 = preg_replace('/\[([1-9][0-9]*)\]/', "<tag id=$1>", $str);
```

Here is a test:

```
$arr = array(
    "I have an apple[1], and another one [2], and another[3]",
    "i have an egg [4], and another egg [5]",
);
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    echo "before: $str\n";
    $str = preg_replace('/\[([1-9]\d*)\]/', "<tag id=$1>", $str);
    echo "after : $str\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
before: I have an apple[1], and another one [2], and another[3]
after : I have an apple<tag id=1>, and another one <tag id=2>, and another<tag id=3>
before: i have an egg [4], and another egg [5]
after : i have an egg <tag id=4>, and another egg <tag id=5>
```

Comment: `$1` will be replaced with the content between [], isn't that what you want?

Comment: very much sorry M42, i thought you mis typed the id=$1,

Comment: what if i had two strings, and want to use same preg_replace, what can i use to continue same increment that first one started??

Comment: @teutara: Sorry, Idon't get what you mean. This will replace `apple[1] and another [2]` by `apple<tag id=1> and another <tag id=2>` isn't that what you want?

Comment: @M42, you perfectly present the solution for the first question, now i edited the original question.

Comment: @inhan: I suppose is to be sure there're no `id=0`.

Comment: @M42, yes it will, but the outcome is 
apple<tag id=1>...egg<tag id=1>, but how to get apple<tag id=1>...egg<tag id=4> ?? (incrementation continues from apples)

Comment: @teutara:see my edit. Is this OK for you? Else, I don't understand what you mean. Please provide some sample inputs and the desired outputs.

Comment: thank you very much M42, i am more than happy with your interest. in fact the second issue was just a typo of mine, as you pointed out earlier, and try to clarify with an example, everything is fine. no problem at all. thank you very much, and sorry i wasted any of your time..

Answer (score 0):

```
        $str="i have an apple[1], and another one [2], and another[3]";
        preg_match_All("/\[[0-9]+\]/",$str,$matches);
        $replace=array();
        for($j=0;$j<count($matches[0]);$j++)
        {
         $replace[]=htmlspecialchars("<tag id=$j>");
        }
         for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
        {
        for($j=0;$j<count($matches[0]);$j++)
        {
        if($i==$j)
        {
         $str=(str_replace($matches[0][$i],$replace[$j],$str));
        }
        }
        }
        echo $str;
```